# Program not running

Tags: ruby

I have been trying to execute the following code using the command prompt. However, when I try to run it I get the following 
C:>circle

C:>

Basically, nothing happens. However, I cannot figure out why this is happening as I am still new to Gosu and Ruby in general. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
require "rubygems"
require "gosu"

class Circle
  attr_reader :columns, :rows

  def initialize(radius)
    @columns = @rows = radius * 2
    img = Gosu::Image.new(Circle.new(50)) 

    img.draw(200, 200, ZOrder::TOP, 0.5, 1.0, Gosu::Color::RED)

    clear, solid = 0x00.chr, 0xff.chr

    lower_half = (0...radius).map do |y|
      x = Math.sqrt(radius ** 2 - y ** 2).round
      right_half = "#{solid * x}#{clear * (radius - x)}"
      right_half.reverse + right_half
    end.join
    alpha_channel = lower_half.reverse + lower_half
    # Expand alpha bytes into RGBA color values.
    @blob = alpha_channel.gsub(/./) { |alpha| solid * 3 + alpha }
  end

  def to_blob
    @blob
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems:

1. You are running file with class definition. What you need to run if you want to look at that blob is `is Circle.new(10).to_blob` - where 10 is radius. You can place it in separate file and require `class.rb`.
2. `initialize` method will be run during `Circle.new()`call. And you have `Circle.new` called in your class:

   `img = Gosu::Image.new(Circle.new(50))`

So it will lead to infinite recursion and will cause `SystemStackError`. AFAIK, there is no built-in empty image constructor in gosu (maybe I am wrong).